# Change css rules for nested elements programmatically

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a `SplitPane` and css file with the following rules:

```
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider {  
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 1;  
    -fx-background-color:-fx-background;
}
```

Now, at runtime I need to change these rules for divider. I tried

```
SplitPane.Divider divider = splitPane.getDividers().get(0);
divider.setStyle("-fx-padding: 1 1 1 1; -fx-background-color:-fx-background;");
```

but there is no method `setStyle` in `SplitPane.Divider` class.

How to change these rules at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to define a new style-class in your CSS file:

```
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 1;
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.modified-split-pane > .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-padding: 1 1 1 1;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

And then in the code add/remove this style class as you need the modified one or the original one:

```
// Modified style
splitPane.getStyleClass().add("modified-split-pane");
// Original style
splitPane.getStyleClass().remove("modified-split-pane")
```

---

You can also use the [`PseudoClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) API:

```
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 1;
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.split-pane:version1 > .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-padding: 1 1 1 1;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

And then in the code active/deactivate this pseudo class:

```
PseudoClass version1Pseudo = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("version1");
splitPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(version1Pseudo, true);
splitPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(version1Pseudo, false);
```

---

There is also a possiblity to set the style attributes in runtime directly in the code by getting the divider `Node`s from the scene-graph using the [`Node#lookupAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-) (or `lookup`) method, **but I highly recommend to avoid this approach**.

```
for (Node node: splitPane.lookupAll(".split-pane-divider"))
    node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-padding: 1 1 1 1;");
```